# Decorator running error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, decorator

I created two variables inside two different decorators, and one decorator works good but the other one shows an error.

```
def running_average(func):
    data = {'total': 0, 'count': 0}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(data)
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        data['total'] += val
        data['count'] += 1
        print('Average of {} so far: {:.01f}'.format(func.__name__,
              data['total']/data['count']))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@running_average
def foo(x):
    return x + 2
```

This foo function works.

```
def countcalls(func):
    count = 0
    print(count)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(count)
        count += 1
        print('# of calls: {}'.format(count))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@countcalls
def boo(x):
    return x + 2
```

But this `boo` function shows error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`.

From my understanding, these two functions follow the same pattern. In both decorators, a variable is defined in the decorator, and the variable is used in the wrapper function. However, this `foo` function works good, but this `boo` function doesn't work. I was wondering what is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the first example, the name `data` always refers to the same object; it is never reassigned.  The dictionary `data` refers to is itself mutated (changed), but it is always the same object.

In contrast, when you do `count += 1` in your second example, that changes the value that the name `count` refers to.  That makes `count` a local variable.  When the interpreter sees this, it notices that you reference the local variable `count` before assigning to it, and fails.

The solution is to tell the interpreter to use the `count` from the enclosing scope by declaring it `nonlocal`

```
def countcalls(func):
    count = 0
    print(count)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal
        print(count)
        count += 1
        print('# of calls: {}'.format(count))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```