# Decorator from class with or without arguments

Tags: python, python-decorators

I try to implement a decorator class and it works fine if I call it with parentheses, but if I try to use it without parentheses it does not work.

How can I make it work without calling it directly if no arguments are passed?

```
class DecByClass:

    def __init__(self, retry=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self._retry = retry

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return retval
        return wrapper
```

This works:

```
@DecByClass()
def try_brackets(t):
    return '2'
```

This doesn't:

```
@DecByClass
def try_brackets(t):
    return '2'
```

What have I missed?

Comment: The first one becomes `try_brackets = DecByClass()(try_brackets)`, the second `try_brackets = DecByClass(try_brackets)`. If you want to handle both use cases, `__call__` and `__init__` must _both_ be able to receive the wrapped function.

Comment: I would recommend just not supporting the use of `@DecByClass` alone. If the decorator *can* take arguments, require `@DecByClass()` even if no arguments are passed.

Comment: It's a ways down, but someone [did provide a class-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611147/364696) to the duplicate.

Comment: @chepner: On the one hand, I agree with you. On the other hand, Python itself has been making a lot of decorators used mostly with defaults allow use without calling them, e.g. [`dataclasses.dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) (always supported it), and [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#functools) (added support for no parens in 3.8, introduced without it in 3.2). The precedents set by the language disagree with both of us.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you please provide code example?

Comment: No, adapting the existing answers for your specific situation is down to you.

Comment: @ShadowRanger There are quite a few precedents and design choices in Python that I disagree with :) This one is particularly egregious though, IMO, as it flies in the face of "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."