# Typing decorators that can be used with or without arguments

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, python-typing, pyright

I have a decorator that can be called either without or with arguments (all strings):

```py
@decorator
def fct0(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a * b


@decorator("foo", "bar")  # any number of arguments
def fct1(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a * b
```

I am having a hard time providing appropriate type hints so that type checkers will be able to properly validate the usage of the decorator, despite having read the [related section of the doc of mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators).

Here is what I have tried so far:

```py
from typing import overload, TypeVar, Any, Callable

F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable[..., Any])

@overload
def decorator(arg: F) -> F:
    ...

@overload
def decorator(*args: str) -> Callable[[F], F]:
    ...

def decorator(*args: Any) -> Any:
    # python code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/q/653368

    # @decorator -> shorthand for @decorator()
    if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
        return decorator()(args[0])

    # @decorator(...) -> real implementation
    def wrapper(fct: F) -> F:
        # real code using `args` and `fct` here redacted for clarity
        return fct

    return wrapper
```

Which results in the following error from `mypy`:

```
error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 1
```

I also have an error with `pyright`:

```
error: Overloaded implementation is not consistent with signature of overload 1
  Type "(*args: Any) -> Any" cannot be assigned to type "(arg: F@decorator) -> F@decorator"
    Keyword parameter "arg" is missing in source
```

*I am using python 3.10.4, mypy 0.960, pyright 1.1.249.*

Comment: Is it really so onerous to have to type `@decorator() def ...`?

Comment: @chepner I guess it depends on the usecase… in my case it's part of the public API of a existing library, and in most cases the decorator will be used without any arguments. Plus I believe typing should help developers instead of limiting them. In the worst case I can always use `# type: ignore` but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: @rogdham Take a look at [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=cd678ce469815849a9ac8b10ffcd24a6)

Comment: @chepner I am not sure that I understand your comment about *static* types; in my case the decorator does not change the type of the decorated function (hence the `Callable[[F], F]`)

Comment: @S.B thank you so much for your playground link, it helped me realize my mistake; I'm writing an answer to explain the issue

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from the first overload (I should have read the `pyright` message twice!):

```py
@overload
def decorator(arg: F) -> F:
    ...
```

This overload accepts a keyword parameter named `arg`, while the implementation does not!

Of course this does not matter in the case of a decorator used with the `@decorator` notation, but could if it is called like so: `fct2 = decorator(arg=fct)`.

## Python >= 3.8

The best way to solve the issue would be to change the first overload so that `arg` is a [positional-only parameter](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) (so cannot be used as a keyword argument):

```py
@overload
def decorator(arg: F, /) -> F:
    ...
```

## With support for Python < 3.8

Since positional-only parameters come with Python 3.8, we cannot change the first overload as desired.

Instead, let's change the implementation to allow for a `**kwargs` parameter (an other possibility would be to add a keyword `arg` parameter). But now we need to handle it properly in the code implementation, for example:

```py
def decorator(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    if kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Unexpected keyword argument")

    # rest of the implementation here
```